# Javascript code runs out of order

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a loading overlay when I am waiting for a pdf to be created using jsPDF but however I try to do this the overlay function is not run. I have tried using a callback function but I think I might be using it incorrectly. The loader changes the opacity of the background and displays a hidden div.

I originally had a call to the loader function in the body of the exporttopdf function but this didnt work so I changed it to be a callback function within the actual loader function. I am lost - please help.

I have created a jsfiddle which is a simplified version of my code to show the issue. An alert starts and the style changes don't kick in.
https://jsfiddle.net/13pkp1xn/295/

Below is the actual code

HTML activated on a button

```
<div class=sidebar>
      <button onclick='loader("start","exporting",function(){exporttopdf();})' class="sidebarbutton">Export</button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function loader(action, text, callback) {

     if (action == "start") {
       document.getElementById("contentbox").style.opacity = 0.4;
       document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = text;
       document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
     } else {
       document.getElementById("contentbox").style.opacity = 1
       document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = "";;
       document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
    }

   if (typeof callback === "function") {
      callback();
   }
}

function exporttopdf() {

  var runnumber = getUrlVars()["runnumber"];
  var doc = new jsPDF();


  var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas");
  for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {

    currentcanvas = canvases[i];
    url_base64jp = currentcanvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
    doc.text(20, 20, currentcanvas.id);
    doc.addImage(url_base64jp, 'png', 15, 40, 180, 160, null, 'FAST');
    doc.addPage();
  }
  doc.save(runnumber + '.pdf')
  loader("stop");

}
```

Comment: document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'This'; document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'is'; document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'a'; document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'very'; document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'inefficient'; document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'way'; document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'to'; document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'write'; document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = 'code';

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, using the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function:

```
if (typeof callback === "function") {
   window.setTimeout(callback, 1);
}
```

By running your callback in a different "Execution Context" you have the feel that both actions executed in parallel.

See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsLazrc4/

Comment: Good Stack Overflow answers should explain what the problem is and how their solution fixes it. Not just "try this".

Answer (score 0):

I edited your fiddle as follows :

JavaScript code :

```
function loader(text, callback) 
{

    document.getElementById("contentbox").style.background = "grey";
    document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";

  if (typeof callback === "function") {
    callback();
  }
}

var exportToPdf = function exporttopdf() {
  alert("exporting");

  setTimeout(function()
  {
    document.getElementById("contentbox").style.background = "pink";
    document.getElementById("loadertext").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  },5000)

}
```

click event on loader button :

```
 <input type='button' value='Just loader' onclick='loader("loading",exportToPdf)'>
```

On clicking the "Just loader" button now , it will apply the changes and then revert back after 5  seconds after alert is handled.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing in your fiddle is that the browser will not redraw the page until your javascript code has exited. `alert` pauses execution until the user clicks `ok`, so while the alert box is visible, you're still stuck in your `exporttopdf` function.

Delayed visual updates aren't the only problem things like this can cause. In fact, the browser won't do *anything at all* until your javascript code has exited. It will be completely unresponsive.

JS in a browser gets around problems like this using asynchronous programming. In short, what you must do is give the browser some kind of event handler and let your functions return. That way, the browser can do its thing and then call the event handler when more JS needs to be run.

Callback functions are a common way of modeling asynchronous programming, but nothing about them is *inherently* asynchronous. What you are doing is simply invoking the callback function *synchronously*, which never gives the browser an opportunity to redraw.

Marcus's answer works because `window.setTimeout` is an *asynchronous* operation. It essentially tells the browser, 'hey, I'm done for now, but in one millisecond I need to do this other thing`. Your code *exits*, the browser redraws, and then-- since at least one millisecond has almost certainly passed-- it starts running your callback.

It is absolutely crucial that you understand this if you want to be a competent web developer. With this understanding should also come the realization of why pdf generation like this on the client side might become problematic when creating large files. If jsPDF is taking long enough that you feel the need to display some loading indication to the user, you probably should not be making these pdfs on the client side, because even if you're showing a message, you're still causing a frustrating browser lock-up while the pdf is being created.

If you really *must* do this on the client side, you may want to look into the possibility of using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Unfortunately, this is a fairly new technology so you might not be able to use it in older browsers.